# jq - Remove duplicated array elements and keep the original sorting order

Tags: json, bash, jq, unique

From the following json I'm aiming to remove the duplicated "type": "change" elements with the same username, but keep the original sorting as it is important. I want to use jq v1.6

```
{
    "title": "recording",
    "steps": [
        {
            "type": "setViewport",
            "width": 1651,
            "height": 1080,
            "deviceScaleFactor": 1,
            "isMobile": false,
            "hasTouch": false,
            "isLandscape": false
        },
        {
            "type": "navigate",
            "url": "chrome://new-tab-page/",
            "assertedEvents": [
                {
                    "type": "navigation",
                    "url": "chrome://new-tab-page/",
                    "title": "New Tab"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "navigate",
            "url": "https://...",
            "assertedEvents": [
                {
                    "type": "navigation",
                    "url": "https://...",
                    "title": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "click",
            "target": "main",
            "selectors": [
                [
                    "aria/org"
                ],
                [
                    "body > div > div.login-box-body > div:nth-child(3) > a"
                ],
                [
                    "xpath//html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/a"
                ],
                [
                    "text/org"
                ]
            ],
            "offsetY": 5,
            "offsetX": 42.79998779296875,
            "assertedEvents": [
                {
                    "type": "navigation",
                    "url": "https:...",
                    "title": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "change",
            "value": "root",
            "selectors": [
                [
                    "aria/Username or email"
                ],
                [
                    "#username"
                ],
                [
                    "xpath///*[@id=\"username\"]"
                ]
            ],
            "target": "main"
        },
        {
            "type": "doubleClick",
            "target": "main",
            "selectors": [
                [
                    "aria/Username or email"
                ],
                [
                    "#username"
                ],
                [
                    "xpath///*[@id=\"username\"]"
                ],
                [
                    "text/root"
                ]
            ],
            "offsetY": 20.79998779296875,
            "offsetX": 71.39996337890625
        },
        {
            "type": "change",
            "value": "root",
            "selectors": [
                [
                    "aria/Username or email"
                ],
                [
                    "#username"
                ],
                [
                    "xpath///*[@id=\"username\"]"
                ]
            ],
            "target": "main"
        },
        {
            "type": "keyDown",
            "target": "main",
            "key": "Tab"
        },
        {
            "type": "keyUp",
            "key": "Tab",
            "target": "main"
        },
        {
            "type": "change",
            "value": "1111",
            "selectors": [
                [
                    "aria/Password"
                ],
                [
                    "#password"
                ],
                [
                    "xpath///*[@id=\"password\"]"
                ],
                [
                    "text/1111"
                ]
            ],
            "target": "main"
        },
        {
            "type": "keyDown",
            "target": "main",
            "key": "Enter",
            "assertedEvents": [
                {
                    "type": "navigation",
                    "url": "https:...",
                    "title": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "keyUp",
            "key": "Enter",
            "target": "main"
        },
        {
            "type": "click",
            "target": "main",
            "selectors": [
                [
                    "aria/ Manager"
                ],
                [
                    "body > div.wrapper > div > section.content > div.row.app-grid > div:nth-child(2) > a"
                ],
                [
                    "xpath//html/body/div[2]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a"
                ]
            ],
            "offsetY": 129,
            "offsetX": 177.79998779296875
        }
    ]
}
```

```
jq -M '.steps[] | select(.value == "root") | unique_by(.value)'
```

yielded error and not sure if this will keep the original sorting:

```
jq: error (at duplicates_testing.json:178): Cannot index string with string "value"
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is "the same username"? As far as I can see, there are no usernames in your JSON input. Also, your proposed jq solution filters for all "root" elements, then takes the unique values (there will only be a single value, because you only select a single value). `unique_by` returns a sorted output

Comment: Voting to close now as this question is missing a the expected output and there was no feedback/clarification from OP in two weeks.